# "name 'word_tokenize' is not defined" in python word count frequency

Tags: python, python-3.x

i am trying to figure out the word frequency from the specific word column.

I want to remove the stopwords from the dictionary.

Here's the code :

## Code

```
import unicodecsv as csv
import nltk
import pandas as pd
import chardet

from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize

with open('data.csv','rb') as f:
    result = chardet.detect(f.read())

file_band = file[file['article'].str.contains("first time")]
file.loc[:,'extracted'] = file_band['article']

top_N = 200

a = file_band['extracted'].str.lower().replace(r'\|', ' ').str.cat(sep=' ')
words = nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(a)
word_dist = nltk.FreqDist(words)
print (word_dist)

stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
word_tokens = word_tokenize(word_dist)

filtered_sentence = [w for w in word_tokens if not w in stop_words]
filtered_sentence = []

for w in word_tokens:
    if w not in stop_words:
        filtered_sentence.append(w)

print(word_tokens)
print(filtered_sentence)
```

## Error

The problem error is:

> NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>        27 #filter words
>        28 stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
>   ---> 29 word_tokens = word_tokenize(word_dist)
>        30 
>        31 filtered_sentence = [w for w in word_tokens if not w in stop_words]
>
> NameError: name 'word_tokenize' is not defined

Comment: Well, it's true. There's no `word_tokenize` function in your code or in your imports.

Comment: Why do you import `sent_tokenize` when you're using `word_tokenize`?

Comment: Before you call `nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(a)`, later you forget about it and just go `word_tokenize(word_dist)`. It can't work.

Comment: thanks ! problem solved :)

Answer (score 8):

> NameError: name 'word_tokenize' is not defined

What the error is telling you is that you are calling a function, `word_tokenize()`, without it being available in your code.

Normally, you would define a function like this:

```
def my_function(my_input):
    words = *do_something_with* my_input
    return words
```

Then you can call it later:

```
words = my_function(my_input)
```

In your case, it looks like you're trying to use a function that is part of the nltk.tokenize module. However, you've only imported part of that module - `sent_tokenize` (which you don't seem to be using btw)

```
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize
```

So maybe you need to import `word_tokenize` instead?

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
```

Or both if you're going to use `sent_tokenize` later?

```
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
```

Answer (score 3):

add following line in beginning of your code
`from nltk import word_tokenize`

Answer (score 3):

I think you need this

```
import nltk

from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
```

Comment: Your answer worked for me, thanks! Do you know why it works though? I'd think `import nltk` would automatically import everything in `nltk`.

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered the same error and found a solution.You first need to run the following code:

```
import nltk
nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger')
```

then the word_tokenize function should work

Answer (score 0):

The word_tokenize function also works using nltk Punkt tokenizer that uses an unsupervised algorithm to split up larger body of text into smaller lines:

```
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
```